# ImportError: "No module named path" in a script python

Tags: python, path

I've a problem with my script python when i try to start.
It's very strange because with other modules os.path works fine

```
import codecs
import io
import sys
import argparse
import logging
import time

from lib.DogechainApi import API


def main():
    # Script argument parsing
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A script to perform bruteforce dictionary attacks on brainwallets.')
    parser.add_argument('-t', action='store', dest='type',help='Dogechain lookup type ({}|{}|{})' .format(API.STRING_TYPE), required=True)
parser.add_argument('-d', action='store', dest='dict_file',help='Dictionary file (e.g. dictionary.txt)', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o', action='store', dest='output_file',help='Output file (e.g. output.txt)', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-k', action='store_true', dest='is_private_key', default=False,
                    help='treat each word as a hex or wif encoded private key, not as brain wallet')
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.1')
args = parser.parse_args()

 # Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-6s line %(lineno)-4s %(message)s')

if args.type != API.STRING_TYPE:
    logging.error("Invalid -t option specified.")
    sys.exit(1)

      # Choose connection type
if args.type == API.STRING_TYPE:
    blockexplorer = Dogechain()
else:
    logging.error("Invalid lookup type specified '{}'".format(args.type))
    sys.exit(1)

# Open session
logging.info("Opening session for {}".format(args.type))
blockexplorer.open_session()

# Open dictionary file and validate encoding
dictionary_encoding = "utf-8"
logging.info("Opening dictionary file {} and validating encoding is {}".format(args.dict_file, dictionary_encoding))
try:
    f_dictionary = io.open(args.dict_file, 'rt', encoding=dictionary_encoding)
    f_dictionary.read(4096)
    f_dictionary.close()
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Failed to open dictionary file {}. Make sure file is {} encoded.".format(
                    args.dict_file, dictionary_encoding))
    sys.exit(1)

# Open dictionary file for reading
logging.info("Opening dictionary file {} for reading".format(args.dict_file))
try:
    # Open file for reading
    logging.info("Opening file with encoding {}".format(dictionary_encoding))
    f_dictionary = io.open(args.dict_file, 'rt', encoding=dictionary_encoding)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Failed to open dictionary file {}. Error: {}".format(
                    args.dict_file, e.args))
    sys.exit(1)

# Open output file for found addresses
file_header = 'dictionary word, received dogecoins, wallet address, private address, current balance'
logging.info("Opening output file {} for writing".format(args.output_file))
try:
    f_found_addresses = codecs.open(args.output_file, 'w', dictionary_encoding)
    logging.info(file_header)
    f_found_addresses.writelines(file_header + '\n')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Failed to open output file {}. Error: {}".format(args.found_file, e.args))
    sys.exit(1)

# Loop through dictionary
for raw_word in f_dictionary:
    dictionary_word = raw_word.rstrip()
    if not dictionary_word:
        continue

    # Print each word since this is rate limited
    if args.type == API.STRING_TYPE:
        logging.info(u"Checking wallet '%s'" % dictionary_word)

    # Create wallet
    try:
        wallet = Wallet(dictionary_word, args.is_private_key)
    except Exception as e:
        continue

    # Get received dogecoins
    retry = 0
    retry_count = 6
    sleep_seconds = 10
    while retry < retry_count:
        try:
            received_dogecoins = blockexplorer.getreceivedbyaddress(wallet.address)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning("Failed to get proper response for received dogecoins. Retry in {} seconds.".format(sleep_seconds))
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
            retry += 1
    if retry == retry_count:
        logging.error("Failed to get response for received dogecoins after {} retries. Skipping.".format(retry_count))
        continue
    if received_dogecoins == 0:
        logging.debug("Received dogecoins is zero.. moving on")
        continue

    # Get current balance
    retry = 0
    retry_count = 5
    sleep_seconds = 15
    while retry < retry_count:
        try:
            current_balance = blockexplorer.get_addressbalance(wallet.address)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning("Failed to get proper response for balance. Retry in {} seconds.".format(sleep_seconds))
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
            retry += 1
    if retry == retry_count:
        logging.error("Failed to get response for balance after {} retries. Skipping.".format(retry_count))
        continue

    # Output results
    output = 'Found used wallet: {},{:.8f},{},{},{:.8f}'.format(dictionary_word, received_dogecoins, wallet.address,
                                                wallet.private_key, current_balance)
    logging.info(output)
    f_found_addresses.write(output + '\n')

# Close files and connection
blockexplorer.close_session()
f_found_addresses.close()
f_dictionary.close()
```

When i run the module, it appears ImportError: "No module named path"

```
Traceback
<module> C:\Python27\dogecoin.py 8 
<module> C:\Python27\lib\DogechainApi.py 11
<module> C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py 94
<module> C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py 70
<module> C:\Python27\lib\os.py 120
ImportError: No module named path
```

Comment: What's the full traceback? The code shown here doesn't try to import `path` anywhere.

Comment: When you reinstall Python is the problem still there? I had a look at line 120 and this error can not happen unless somebody plays with the import mechanism or the standard library file path is not existent.